# Hudson doesn't like Grails

Tags: grails, hudson, ivy

I'm trying to get our CI-Server Hudson to run grails tasks and installed the Grails-Plugin, but it seems like the dependencies with ivy could not be resolved...

```
[projectx] $ /usr/share/grails/bin/grails prod war projectx.war
Welcome to Grails 1.2.0 - http://grails.org/
Licensed under Apache Standard License 2.0
Grails home is set to: /usr/share/grails

Base Directory: /var/local/hudson/jobs/projectx/workspace/projectx
Resolving dependencies...
Error executing script War: /usr/share/tomcat5.5/.ivy2/cache/resolved-projectx-projectx-0.1.xml (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/share/tomcat5.5/.ivy2/cache/resolved-projectx-projectx-0.1.xml (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) ...
```

Does anyone know how to get this working?

Thanks alot!

Comment: Did you set the work dir in Hudson's Grails-Plugin configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the user that tomcat is running as is configured to have `/usr/share/tomcat5.5` as the home directory and you don't have write access to that directory (*and probably shouldn't*)

I'd guess that you need to modify the user that tomcat is running as, or the user that the Hudson Job is running as to have a valid home directory.

Comment: I agree, it will be due to file permissions stoping the .ivy folder being created.

Comment: Thanks, that got me a bit further. I've created /home/tomcat with appropriate permissions and changed the tomcat's home, but unfortunately there is another error...

After some compiling, copying and mkdir-ing the build process fails with:


Error executing script War: : Replace: source file /home/tomcat55/.grails/1.2.0/projects/comtecdb/stage/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml doesn't exist
gant.TargetExecutionException: : Replace: source file /home/tomcat55/.grails/1.2.0/projects/comtecdb/stage/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml doesn't exist ...

Comment: SOLVED! I run an "grails upgrade --non-interactive" first and it works.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add web-app/WEB-INF to your version control.

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
grails upgrade
```

and it will work afterwards. I tried deleting .grails folder and it did not work and discovered that upgrade works by accident.

On Jenkins you can run it with a --non-interactive switch.

Anyone figured out why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Hudson supports maven based builds very well so you could just use the Grails Maven Plugin http://www.grails.org/Maven+Integration and point hudson at the maven pom file and away you go.